# NoMethodError in #new - form_for, but resources set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm trying some steps into rails and searched around SO, but couldn't find any answer. I constantly get `NoMethodError undefined method` for Line 1 as soon as I browse to `/tswhois/new`. Whats wrong?

**controllers/tswhois_controller.rb**

```
class TswhoisController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tswhois = Tswhois.all
  end

  def new
    @tswhois = Tswhois.new
  end
end
```

---

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tswhois
end
```

---

**views/tswhois/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for (@tswhois) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.text_field :url %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

---

**console**

```
rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
2.1.5 :001 > Tswhois.count
   (10.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tswhois`
 => 0
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remember conventions in rails: model name is singular ie no `s` or `es` at the end. Routing is built around your model name. Your error page suggests Rails doesn't get the correct route for the action, in this example `new` action.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy and paste the entire error message ? try also: `<%= form_for(@tswhois) do |f| %>` without space and with the = sign

Comment: tried w/o space and w/o `=` in form_for. Updated question with screenshot. Still getting the error

Comment: try `<%= form_for @twhois do |f| %>`

Comment: There might be a problem with the model's name, because it has an "s" at the end but I'm not really sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the server after adding the resources to the routes.rb? the code you provided for your routes file is missing 'end' at the end of it.

Comment: I did a restart of WEBrick and...a complete system restart (just to be super sure) :) And the `routes.rb` got an end, I just missed copy/paste it here.

Comment: Are you missing 'end' at the end of the file?
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tswhois
end

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `views/tswhois/new.html.erb` code. The code snippet you posted is probably from `views/tswhois/_form.html.erb`

It probably has a line `<%= link_to 'something', tswhois_index_path %>`

Change it to

```
<%= link_to 'something', tswhois_path %>
```

Thing is, the name 'tswhois' is going to be rather confusing due to the convention of singular and plural for a single instance and array of instances respectively.